# Unity animation not playing at low sample rate

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation, sample-rate

I'm using Unity 2019.4.24f1. I have a simple animation of 2 sprites. 1 for 2 frames, then the other for 2 frames. At a sample rate of 12 the animation plays perfectly, only too fast. If I lower the sample rate to 6, then the animation doesn't play. At 8 it plays once and then stops. If I keep the sample rate at 12 and double the amount of frames each sprite should be shown, I get the same result: no animation. I can't figure out how to get those two sprites to switch slowly using the animation system in Unity.

EDIT: Here's what it looks like. I changed the keyframes and that changed the values for the different things the system does, but the results are the same.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-qIu6BqtvA

Answer (score 0):

It looks like changing the samples field is prone to glitches like this. The suggested way to change how fast an animation plays is the 'Animation Speed' field in the inspector when selecting an animation from the Animator window.

So if your animation is set to 1, and is too fast, try changing it to .5.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Unfortunately changing the speed from that field yielded the same results.